# How to color the matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, graph-coloring

Is there exist a way to color a plot in matlab? For example my x and y coordinate are between 0 and 1. I want to give a red zone to the area which x times y is less than 0.5 and yellow for the rest.

Thank you.

Comment: See [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) or [`area`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html).

Comment: You mean an [`area`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) plot?

Comment: Yes, I mean an are in the plot. I want to divide the plot into 2 areas, red and yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pcolor` to generate a pseudocolor-plot. To get the values of `x*y` just do an appropriate matrix-multiplication to get `M`. `M` can be compared with 0.5 with `M<0.5`. This returns a logical-matrix that is converted to a double with the `double`-function and is then passed to `pcolor`. Then we set a colormap containing red and yellow. Finally we can apply `shading flat` or `shading interp` (additionally interpolates), so the lines between the patches disappear.

```
x = linspace(0,1,1000);
y = x;

M = x'*y;

pcolor(x,y,double(M<0.5));
colormap([1,1,0;1,0,0]);
shading interp
```

*This is the result:*
[image: result1]

**Edit:** If you want several areas with different colors, just add a new color to the colormap and edit the color-argument of `pcolor` accordingly. The following code generates a three-zone plot:

```
x = linspace(0,1,1000);
y = x;

M = x'*y;
C = double(M<0.5)+double(M<0.75);

pcolor(x,y,C);
colormap([0,1,0;1,1,0;1,0,0]);
shading flat
```

*The result looks like this:*
[image: result2]

Comment: Thank you this is just what I needed. But is it possible to make it three regions? Let's say if x times y is 0 to 0.5 is red, 0.5 to 0.75 is yellow and the rest is green.

Comment: @GregoriusEdwadr: I edited my answer to include an example of a three-zone plot.